# Unique roecords with CTE and UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, union

I have one table consists of three fields, TagID, AlarmInfo and Description. TagID always starts with a prefix followed by "_HH", "_H","_L","_LL" OR the suffix can be customizing. If the suffix is customizing, then AlarmInfo must be specified. The AlarmInfo field consists of two parts, alarm type  and order index.

Ex table
[image]

I've tried something like that:

**Code:**

```
WITH
CTE1 AS
(
SELECT [TagID],[AlarmInfo],[Description],CASE WHEN [AlarmInfo] = ''  OR [AlarmInfo] IS NULL OR CHARINDEX('|',[AlarmInfo],0) = 0 THEN 999 
ELSE IIF(ISNUMERIC(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([AlarmInfo]),1,CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE([AlarmInfo]),0)-1))) = 1,
CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([AlarmInfo]),1,CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE([AlarmInfo]),0)-1)) AS INT),999) END AS [OrderIndex],
CASE WHEN [TagID] LIKE '%_%' THEN LEFT([TagID],CHARINDEX('_',[TagID])-1) ELSE [TagID] END TagPrefix 
FROM Table1),

CTE2 AS (SELECT [TagID],[AlarmInfo],[Description], 1 [OrderIndex] FROM Table1 WHERE TagID  LIKE '%FT01_HH'),
CTE3 AS (SELECT [TagID],[AlarmInfo],[Description], 4 [OrderIndex] FROM Table1 WHERE TagID  LIKE '%FT01_LL')

SELECT [TagID],[AlarmInfo],[Description],[OrderIndex] FROM CTE1 WHERE (TagPrefix = 'FT01') AND [AlarmInfo] LIKE 'AlarmLimit%'-- 
UNION
SELECT * FROM CTE2
UNION
SELECT * FROM CTE3
ORDER BY [OrderIndex] ASC
```

[image]

The result is that the FT01_LL is duplicated. If I remove [OrderIndex] from the Query, then UNION return only unique rows, but then I am missing the imported order index information.

[image]

I am using MS SQL server 2014.

Comment: You should post sample data as text, from SQL Server Management Studio is as easy as go to `Query > Results to > Results to text` (or press `Ctrl+T`).

Comment: Also, it is more helpful to add the schema and data scripts to create the test set. Without that, you are asking us to create a test dataset. And... we might not create a test dataset that matches your need.